# How can I dump an ActiveModel record as an INSERT SQL statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-7, arel

Previously with Rails 6 I have been doing:

```
    # I have an existing record
    record = MyRandomModel.take

    # Now I wanna get the INSERT SQL which would have been generated and executed on the DB in case it was a new record....

    model = record.class
    values = record.send(:attributes_with_values, record.send(:attributes_for_create, model.column_names))

    substitutes_and_binds = model.send(:_substitute_values, values)

    insert_manager = model.arel_table.create_insert
    insert_manager.insert substitutes_and_binds

    sql = model.connection.unprepared_statement do
      model.connection.to_sql(insert_manager)
    end

    puts sql
    #=> "INSERT...."
```

However this procedure does not work in rails 7. It fails with the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `_substitute_values' for MyRandomModel:Class
```

**UPDATE:**
I got this far:

```
  record = MyRandomModel.take
  model = record.class
  table = model.arel_table
  # Create an InsertManager object
  insert_manager = Arel::InsertManager.new(table)
  insert_manager.insert(
    record.send(:attributes_with_values, model.column_names).transform_keys { |name| table[name] }
  )
  insert_manager.to_sql
```

However it produces a prepared INSERT statement without the actual values...

Comment: "this procedure does not work" ... we need a better explanation. Which step fails, what error message? What have you tried?

Comment: Is _substitute_values a method that you yourself have written, or are you expecting that Rails provides this? If the answer is Rails, by convention underscore methods are not for public use. It would not be a surprise if such a method existed in Rails 6 and not in Rails 7.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? It looks as if `SomeModel.arel_table.create_insert` falls in Rails 7 too!

Comment: So yeah, the point is, I used to do it like that, using internal rails methods (which I know are not part of the public API). What I'm trying to do again is to generate and capture the INSERT SQL statement generated based on the record

Comment: @LesNightingill right - that one too is gone in rails 7 - now I think you have to do: insert_manager = Arel::InsertManager.new(record.class.arel_table)

Comment: Instead of digging around and trying to use internal Rails methods, IMHO your time wouild be better spent figuring out how to achieve your objective using the public API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I got it:

```
  record = MyRandomModel.take
  model = record.class
  table = model.arel_table
  # Create an InsertManager object
  insert_manager = Arel::InsertManager.new(table)
  insert_manager.insert(
    record.send(:attributes_with_values, model.column_names).transform_keys { |name| table[name] }
  )
  model.connection.unprepared_statement do
    model.connection.to_sql(insert_manager)
  end
```